# What is the best way to start designing this website?

Tags: website-design, css, react

I am new UI(ReactJS) Developer, I want to develop this webpage from scratch, however, I am not that experienced, hence, confused how to actually start. Should i start with logo or header or sidebar or containers. I also want containers and header to be responsive. Should i make use of Grid and flexbox, Should i completely develop the layout with Grid. What CSS reset should i implement. What is the recommended max-width, Is it okay to reset it like this

```
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; 
  box-sizing: border-box
}`
```

[image]
Any other suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thank you !!

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question like supported browsers, resolutions, mobile responsive info's? Since, flex-box are not supported by older versions of some browsers.

Comment: I have elaborated my question.

Comment: this is a question for UI/dev, not UX

Comment: Regardless of where you ask this, it's quite a broad question and will most likely be closed. You need to narrow it down to a single problem, check [ask].

Comment: Not only is it broad but it's thoroughly off topic as it asks for programming decisions, opinion, and design implementation. https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the DOM structure, you may follow this - 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

For CSS reset, I use this most of the time

```
/*--- css reset ---*/

* {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    outline:none;
}
```

Preferably use grid to layout out the elements since it is going to be responsive. Because there is a sidebar, the max-width should be 100% with the sidebar comfortably placed on one side. The side-bar usually has fixed width (about 300px), then use the rest of the page-width for the content.